# Calculating geodesic distance between GPS points in python

Tags: python, gps, geopandas

I'm trying to calculate distance between 2 gps points.

I came across this code below.

it seem to work but I don't understand why using to_crs(epsg=3310,inplace=True)
does the trick.

and what exactly is the role of crs in geopandas.

```
geom=[Point(xy) for xy in zip([117.454361,117.459880],[38.8459879,38.846255])]
gdf=GeoDataFrame(geometry=geom,crs={'init':'epsg:4326'})
gdf.to_crs(epsg=3310,inplace=True)
dis=gdf.distance(gdf.shift())
print(dis)
---------
0           NaN
1    479.450134
```

Comment: You do not need it.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi without it i get answer as an angle and not meters

0         NaN
1    0.005525

Comment: Right, and your question is duplicated (in comment) in https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/293342/67005. I confess I never used geoPandas for such calculations. I would use pyproj (which it is used by geopandas). Check http://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/api/geod.html#pyproj.Geod.line_length